# Custom Translation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, localisation, translate

I cannot make translation for Magento 2. What I've been doing is:

1. Created a custom theme
2. Now I want to apply some german translations
3. Made a csv in `vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv`
4. Tried to `bin/magento i18n:pack app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/de_DE.csv de_DE`

But then an error occurs I don't know what to make of:

```
  Each row has to consist of 4 columns: original phrase, translation, context type, context value
```

My `.csv` content looks like:

```
"Search entire store here...", "Produktsuche"
```

What's the right way to make some lean theme tranlations without building an own language pack?

Comment: Could it be a encoding problem. Check this out: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101692/problem-when-create-a-language-package-for-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

**First run below command to collect phrases**

> bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -m -o [test.csv]

You can see test.csv file in your Magento root folder. 
Open file in excel and change 2nd column content

**Second run below command**

> bin/magento i18n:pack test.csv de_DE -d

**Note:-**

1. Change test.csv file based on your requirements.
2. de_DE change based on your requirements.

I hope this is helpful to you.
Let me know if you still facing any issue.

Comment: this works for me. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I the meantime I found out that there needs also to be the definition of module and module name there.

Looking like this, the error disappears:

```
"Search entire store here...", "Produktsuche",module,Magento_Search
"Sort By",Sortieren,module,Magento_Catalog
"Shop By",Filter,module,Magento_Catalog
```